# How to manage multi-software projects

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I'm evaluating Jira and I have the following scenario in my company:

There are the softwares X, Y and Z and each one has a release and a version.
When a new project is created we would create the issues and associate them with each software and its respective release.

It seems to me that the component is an alternative but would not have associated software's version.

How could I manage this on Jira?

Comment: Are X, Y and Z projects?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/using-jira-for-project-management-193299132.html), `JIRA` supports the following hierarchy for software delivery management:

JIRA has a 4 level hierarchy: 
Project > Components (logical subsections) and Versions (phases/milestones) > Issues > Subtasks.

[image]

### What is a release?

To answer your question, we need to clarify what a `release` actually is?

In fact, *a `release` is a special state of a software `version`.*

In other terms, as explained in this Atlassian documentation [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-versions-802592484.html), a `software version` is equivalent to a `project milestone`. You reach this milestone after resolving all the issues that you have assigned to the software `version`. After one or more versions, your software product has enough features and is stable enough, so you deliver it to your clients. At this stage, the software `version` that you delivered to your clients, or in other terms **`released`**, is called `a release`.

Practically, as explained in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-versions-802592484.html), JIRA enables you to assign the `status released` to a `software version`.